# Is convergent that series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to know if this series is convergent (and why)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sin\left(\frac{n\,\pi}{6}\right)\,\right)^n$$

Answer (score 2):

The $n$-th term does not tend to $0$, so the sum does not converge

Comment: But $-1\leq \sin(*)\leq1 $ and then $\sin^n(*)$ tends to $0$. Is this wrong?

Comment: @ppooppii Yes, but there are value of $n$ for which $sin( n *pi/6)=1$. Moreover, there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: @ppooppii what is "$\sin^n(*)$ tends to $0$" supposed to mean here?  If you specifically mean that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sin(n \pi/6) \right)^n = 0
$$
then you're wrong

Comment: Yes, I would like to write this $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sin(n \pi/6) \right)^n = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Replacing summation with limits to $\infty$ we get ${lim -> \infty} (sin(\frac{\pi.n}{6}))^n$ so this got no closed form.  Thus series is divergent.